# Solr Cloud: Inconsistent Result

Tags: solr

We are using Solr Cloud (4.3) for indexing data. We have 2 shard/2 replica servers in Solr Cloud.

We tried executing query on individual shard and it shows correct

When we execute same query (*:*) from Solr Admin Console, it display inconsistent results (number of records found is different each time).

What could be wrong?  How can we troubleshoot it?

How Query is executed on different (shard/replica) and result combine?  Is there any document which explain details about this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to make sure that solr is doing soft commits to push information to the other replicas.  This needs to be set to the frequency that you need the data to stay "current"

```
solr.autoSoftCommit.maxDocs=<max number of uncommitted documents before soft commit>
solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime=<max time in ms before soft commit>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml

[SOLR autoCommit vs autoSoftCommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654266/solr-autocommit-vs-autosoftcommit)

Answer (score 0):

Do a commit operation on solr Cloud after you index your data. Then refresh your results,One or two times it might show you different results,But after that it should be pretty consistent.