# SEVERE UpdateLog Error inspecting tlog tlog in Solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr cloud with 2 nodes in production.
Solr stopped accepting writes , this it the error i get in the master node.

```
SEVERE  UpdateLog   Error inspecting tlog tlog{file=/var/lib/solr/core_0/data/tlog/tlog.0000000000001264986 refcount=2}
WARNING     SolrCore    [core_1] PERFORMANCE WARNING: Overlapping onDeckSearchers=2
SEVERE  SolrCmdDistributor  forwarding update to http://Solr02:8983/solr/core_1/ failed - retrying ...
SEVERE  SolrCore    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your tlogs, sometimes when you don't commit for a long time tlogs become huge, you need to commit to free them, maybe you add documents with softCommit true, or maybe your autocommit & autosoftcommit config values aren't good in your case.
These links can help you understand more :

http://lucidworks.com/blog/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/

[SOLR autoCommit vs autoSoftCommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654266/solr-autocommit-vs-autosoftcommit)