# How does ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient handle update request?

Tags: multithreading, solr, solrj

My application intends to insert documents to Solr regularly. There are two considerations:

1. Sending update request to Solr is key impact to the performance.
2. Thread safe of transaction. The commit of SolrClient is not thread-safe(point this out if I'm wrong), this might cause serious problem when multiple users input document to Solr.

I found `ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient` is a candidate solution that it is thread-safe, and it has a queue to buffer and flush many documents in one connection. But I am confused when I test it. My question is,

1. If I set the queue size, should I still need to commit?
2. If I commit, even there is only one document in the queue, it still submit a http request to Solr. Can I make it working as message queue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SolrClient` is thread-safe and you can share a `SolrClient` instance across multiple threads if your insert/update/delete are stick to one collection or core into the Solr instance.

But Solr hasn't the transactions as you could imagine have in a classic RDBMS.

You must be aware that if you have more `SolrClient` instances (in the same app or in different apps and servers) that concurrently updates a collection/core, the first client that sends a commit to that collection/core, commits all the updates done till that moment by every client.

On the other hand, if a `SolrClient` instances sends a rollback, it rollbacks all the updates done (even by the other SolrClient clients).

There are many strategies to updates concurrently documents in Solr, and to understand how the commit works in Solr I warmly recommend to read

- [Understanding Transaction Logs, Soft Commit and Commit in SolrCloud](https://lucidworks.com/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/)
- [Solr Near Realtime Search](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/near-real-time-searching.html)
- [SOLR autoCommit vs autoSoftCommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654266/solr-autocommit-vs-autosoftcommit)

And if you're writing your own multithread application I have just to recommend to centralise the commits and rollbacks in one point.

> [`ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_9_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.html) buffers all added documents and writes them
> into open HTTP connections. **This class is thread safe**.
>
> **Although
> any SolrClient request can be made with this implementation, it is
> only recommended to use ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient with /update
> requests.** The class HttpSolrClient is better suited for the query
> interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good reference. I understand what is the softcommit and hardcommit. The most important idea is "Do not do any kind of commit from client" -- Erick Erickson.

Comment: I’m glad to see my answer is useful :)