# Solr cannot write to config directory.switching to in memory storage instead

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr8.4.1

I am trying to create a solr core using this api

http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=super&instanceDir=/home/ubuntu/solr-8.8.2/server/solr/super&configSet=stored_false

the core is created fine but i got this warning

[image]

Can any one explain me this and how to solve this warning.And what effects it show on searching and indexing.

Comment: Give the user that solr runs under proper access to its directories; otherwise any changes to the configuration won't be persisted. Make sure you can restart your solr instance (.. and reboot the server) and everything is still there as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential explanations, but both start by checking whether that *conf* directory actually exists.

The first one is to properly check the permissions, as mentioned by MatsLindh.

The other is to check if your custom configset (*stored_false*) contains its configuration files straight under the directory, rather than under *conf* subdirectory like the default configsets do.

Solr accepts both directory layouts, but at least sometimes (always? recently? docker-only?), the flat layout will create the core fine but will not be able to do subsequent things with it. Fixing your configset to include *conf* subdirectory and moving files there solves the problem.

Comment: This solved it for me — moving the files from `configsets/<set-name>` to `configsets/<set-name>/conf`.